# How to add altera lib for simulation with ModelSim?

Tags: simulation, fpga, modelsim, intel-fpga, quartus

After compiling a project (with Quartus) with a top-level file (VHDL) and an Altera specific PLL, I tried to simulate it with ModelSim.

When I start the RTL simulation, I see my top-level file in the folder `work` (in the Library Window), but not the Altera instance for the PLL (Verilog file).

**Question:** 
How can I setup Quartus or ModelSim in order to see my top-level file **AND** the Altera instance for the PLL?

Comment: You can not use inbult hardcore IP accessible for your usage.

Comment: Are you using the ModelSim (Altera Edition) shipped with Quartus? It should already contain all Altera vendor libraries. If you are using an external simulator like QuestaSim, then you can compile the Altera vendor libraries from the Quartus main menu (Tools => Launch Simulation Library Compiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Altera specific modules like PLLs, are easiest to simulate using the ModelSim Altera Edition (available with Altera Quar5us) which contains a number of pre-compiles libraries with packages and entities for the Altera specific blocks.  If not already using this ModelSim Altera Edition.  You can see the Altera libraries in the ModelSim Altera Starter Edition (free) below.

[image]

Then you simply compile all the modules into a library, including the Altera Quartus generated wrapper for the PLL, the wrapper should then have references to the available Altera libraries with the simulation model of the PLL.

If this does not work, then please reduce your code to an example that shows the problem and can be posted here; see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Just compile like you would any vhld/verilog source code:

```
vcom *.vhd
vlog *.v
vlog -sv *.sv
```

The simulation models are available with Quartus install. Assuming you have Quartus installed at QUARTUS_DIR for example, to compile some VHDL simulation models you'd do:

```
vlib work;
vcom -work work QUARTUS_DIR/eda/sim_lib/altera_mf_components.vhd
vcom -work work QUARTUS_DIR/eda/sim_lib/altera_mf.vhd
```

You'd need to pay attention to the order of compilation in most cases.
You can create an Altera model simulation library and then just map it so that you don't have to compile the same code for each of your projects.